# Invalid Date: Invalid time zone error in downloading emails, lumisoft.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, imap, lumisoft

I am using lumisoft.net.dll for reading/polling emails from my mailbox & logging them in database.

Here's the code

```
private List<IMAP_Envelope> GetNewReplies()
{
    List<IMAP_Envelope> lstNewReplies = new List<IMAP_Envelope>() { };

    using (IMAP_Client client = new IMAP_Client())
    {
        client.Connect(Common.IMAPHost, Common.IMAPPort, Common.SSL);
        client.Login(Common.ReplyTo, Common.ReplyToPassword);
        client.SelectFolder("INBOX");

        IMAP_SequenceSet sequence = new IMAP_SequenceSet();
        //sequence.Parse("*:1"); // from first to last

        IMAP_Client_FetchHandler fetchHandler = new IMAP_Client_FetchHandler();
        fetchHandler.NextMessage += new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs eNexMessage) { });
        fetchHandler.Envelope += new EventHandler<EventArgs<IMAP_Envelope>>(delegate(object s, EventArgs<IMAP_Envelope> eEnvelope)
        {
            lstNewReplies.Add(eEnvelope.Value);
        });

        // the best way to find unread emails is to perform server search
        Int32[] unseen_ids = client.Search(false, null, "unseen");

        if (unseen_ids.Length > 0)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sbUnseenIDs = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (Int32 unseen_id in unseen_ids)
            {
                if (sbUnseenIDs.Length <= 0)
                {
                    sbUnseenIDs.Append(Convert.ToString(unseen_id));
                }
                else
                {
                    sbUnseenIDs.Append("," + Convert.ToString(unseen_id));
                }
            }

            // now we need to initiate our sequence of messages to be fetched                    
            sequence.Parse(sbUnseenIDs.ToString());

            // fetch messages now                    
            IMAP_Fetch_DataItem[] lstDataItem = new IMAP_Fetch_DataItem[] { new IMAP_Fetch_DataItem_Envelope() };
            client.Fetch(false, sequence, lstDataItem, fetchHandler);

            //this line marks messages as read
            client.StoreMessageFlags(false, sequence, IMAP_Flags_SetType.Add, IMAP_MessageFlags.Seen);

            //this line marks messages as deleted
            client.StoreMessageFlags(false, sequence, IMAP_Flags_SetType.Add, IMAP_MessageFlags.Deleted);
        }

        //client.CloseFolder();
        client.Expunge();
        client.Disconnect();
        client.Dispose();
    }

    return lstNewReplies;
}
```

This works fine mostly, but sometimes it starts throwing exception on

```
client.Fetch(false, sequence, lstDataItem, fetchHandler);
```

`Invalid Date: Invalid time zone.`

I have noticed that it happens when someone sends an email through their blackberry phone, or through some lesser known email-clients.

If I delete the problematic emails which are sent by blackberry phone, by going into the web interface for the mailbox, it starts working again.

Where should I start looking to get around this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with lumisoft, but at this point I would consider using a more recent dll. Or you will have to consider editing lumisoft code if available.

Comment: @tschmit007 Yes, I have been looking for other dlls/options as well. But lumisoft is free & open source so it is my first preference. I'd choose other option if I need to edit lumisoft code.

Comment: well free isn't always better.. sounds like you will have to edit the existing dll..

Comment: We bought MailBee. Its been all most 6 months. And its working like a charm. Client had to pay for it though ;). Just thought to provide update, in case anybody is interested.